# Application to order undated photos?

Tags: photo-management, photography, photo-editing

Before trying to code my own solution...

I have about 3,000 photo slides that I am digitizing with a scanner. I put the scanned images in folders corresponding to years. I'd like an application that would let me view all the photos in a folder and then re-order them, either by dragging-and-dropping images in a light table fashion, or have them in a list so I could move them forward or backward in the list.

I've become quite familiar with Darktable, and use it to edit the photos, but it doesn't have a feature to reorder photos (as far as I can see).

I can't use a program to sort by EXIF data because these photos don't have specific EXIF dates (other than the scan date). I need to set the order manually.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Reordering means renaming?

Comment: Yep: Ideally, I'd like the program to prepend ascending numbers to reflect the new order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After failing to find a solution, I wrote a Python GUI app: "Tripod."

You can download it at https://github.com/trinkner/tripod.  It should work on Linux, Windows, and Mac.

Tripod lets you drag and drop image files into the sequence of your choosing and then rename them automatically according to the sequence. For example, if you have 100 slides of a trip to San Francisco, you can order them and then have Tripod name them "SanFrancisco_1.jpg," "SanFrancisco_2.jpg," etc. You can use Tripod to insert photo date and time into the filename (e.g., "2018-11-15_124532-SanFrancisco.jpg".  Tripod can also append data or sequential number to existing filenames. You can also use Tripod to edit EXIF data inside your image files, like photo date, camera and lens manufacturer, copyright, etc. Tripod also lets you shift photo time, in case your camera's date/time wasn't set properly when you took the photos. Finally, you can use Tripod to adjust image rotation settings.

Here's a screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try **digiKam** (Find similar photos\images, Move to Album, Tags functions ...) or **XnView** (Tags, Move To, and lot of another good functions ...)